# Implement Charts in Flutter using WebViews

Tags: flutter, dart, d3.js, charts, webview

We‘re trying to build an app which needs to display some data as line-/bar-charts

Since the current flutter chart libraries are not good enough yet, we‘re thinking about using a WebView to display d3 charts. My first experiments show that updating a WebView is really slow and blocks the other UI. This will stop us from implementing this solution if we don‘t find a fix.

Is it possible to optimize WebViews to be performant enough to display Charts which are updated from the flutter widget?

**I tried to build a widget with the following idea:**

- Create a Chart with HTML/JavaScript and save the HTML to the constant kChart
- Insert the data which is loaded from the flutter app into this HTML-string
- Load this HTML-string in the WebView
- Display it

this is the generated code:

```
class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data; // Data as encoded JSON. This will be inserted into the Chart-HTML

  Chart(this.data);

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  var loading = true;
  String data = "";
  WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    data = widget.data;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller != null && widget.data != data) {
      setState(() {
        loading = true;
        data = widget.data;
        loadPage(controller);
      });
    }
    return Stack(children: [
      AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: loading ? 0.1 : 1,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: WebView(
          onPageStarted: (s) {
            setState(() {
              loading = true;
            });
          },
          onPageFinished: (s) {
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
            });
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
            print("Def LOAD PAGE");
            this.controller = controller;
            loadPage(controller);
          },
        ),
      ),
      Visibility(
          visible: loading, child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
    ]);
  }

  void loadPage(WebViewController controller) async {
    var chartHTML = kChart.replaceAll("{{DATA}}", widget.data); // load the Chart-HTML from a konstant in another file. Insert the data into this konstant
    final String contentBase64 =
        base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(chartHTML));
    await controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
When refreshing the data (e.g adding a new data-point or remove one) the reload takes a) a long period of time and b) blocks the other UI from updating -> the app lags

Comment: How did you guys solved this?
Switched back to a flutter native charting library or managed to have d3 working nicely?

Comment: Created my own Chart-Widget which is optimized for our specific usecase

Answer (score 0):

Try with this library: https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart

It is working pretty good actually!